# Get List of Multiple Selected Options in Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a function where i am displaying a multile select box, it shows the items in the select box and some comes up as already selected, What i am trying to do is;

select the items by dragging a mouse to select all, using a click on the item or there are all ways by which which we can select the items within the select box, be it mouse or keyboard., I am trying to show/hide contents based upon one of the selection of select box which is `MD`. On Page, i am trying that if `MD` is selected, it should keep the `div` opened.

here is my try but i am failing in this because my knowledge in javascript is very less, if someone can point me in right direction, that will be great

Here is my try:

```
<select id="assignType" onChange="checkASelection()" size="5" name="assignType" class="inputMultiLong" multiple>        
                                <option value="M">List 1</option>
                                <option value="MS">List 2</option>
                                <option value="MD">List 3</option>
                            </select>   

<div class="tabRow" id="annsection" style="display:none;">
my code here 
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function checkASelection() {
        var thisVal = document.getElementById('assignType').value;
        alert(thisVal);
        if(thisVal == 'MD') {
            document.getElementById('annsection').style.display='block';
        }
    }
```

Want to in javascript but jquery is also an option which i am check

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to archieve, but i guess you want to get all the selected options, do you?

If so, you could do something like this in JQuery:

```
$('select#assignType').val();
```

This will return you all the selcted options

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gya6mwmb/3/

Comment: almost near the edge, can u try same in javascript, because the way we i am tryig is if i select either with mouse or keyboard, it should always the display the div when the MD is selected, i see that it is coming as list when i select all, also if i refresh the page, how can i detect if the already selected is MD, it should keep the div in block state

Comment: i've updatet the fiddle, but still i'm not sure what you trying to archieve sorry. Maybe the updatet fiddle helps you a bit. After a page refresh it's not possible to check if the `MD` was already selected, unless you are saving the state of the select element in a database / cookie or something

Comment: That i am doing that, i am saving the state in database, can you guide me that how

Comment: To explain all this here would go beyond the scope. But there a enough tutorials how to do this :)

Comment: if i save the page by selecting the MD and come again back to the same page, I see that MD item selected but in that case, the div does not display, basically it should show, all good, i think this is causing one last issue we are having, else we are all good...

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery `inArray` method:

```
$(function(){
$("#assignType").click(function(){
    var indice = $.inArray("MD",$(this).val()) ;   
    if(indice == -1){
        $("#annsection").hide();
    }
    else{
         $("#annsection").show();
    }
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/voknxtL0/3/